# An object with the name already exist in the database just when I use constraint

Tags: sql-server

When I use this script:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableX', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE dbo.TableX

CREATE TABLE TableX
(
    ...
    ...
    ...

    CONSTRAINT TableX PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2, column3)
)
```

I get an error

> An object with the name 'TableX' already exist in the database

but that is only when I use the `CONSTRAINT` line.

Why do I get an error only when I use `CONSTRAINT` and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because your Constaint name is the same as table name. Name it like PK_TableX

Comment: Thank you Anton that solve it, but I have another script where I use the table name in the constraint and works fine.

Comment: It's a general practice to use prefixes for different object types, like PK_ for primary keys, FK_ for foreign keys, UQ_ for unique constraints, DF_ for defaults, etc. The uniqueness requirement for object names is not well documented, so it may depend on SQL Server version or when/where/how the object was created.

Answer (score 1):

Tables and constraints all are treated as objects in SQL Server database.
Check `sys.objects` system table.

So you cannot have the same name for Table and Constraint. When you run the create statement, SQL server will first creates the table and then tries to create the Constraint which fails as the name already exists in `sys.objects` for table.

Try a different name for the primary key constraint. As per standards, primary keys are prefixed with `PK_`. So here you can name your primary key as `PK_TableX`

Comment: That's not correct. You can create an index with same name as table name, at least on SQL 2016. The index is not in sys.objects table, only constraint, btw. The problem was with constraint name.

Comment: @Anton : my bad, was referring to the constraint not index. edited.